# how to store large list of ids in the browser uri

Tags: javascript, url, browser, uri, query-string

I have a multi select on a webpage. The multi select value is an array of IDs and is handled on the client and stored in browser's uri, in query-string.

After the page is loaded or the filter (multi select) is changed, then the query-string is updated, decoded and extracted IDs are used to make the request to the API.

The purpose of this is to allow users to save the value of this filter in a browser bookmark, and also to allow them to share it via a link.

Each ID is 36 characters length string. But the uri of some browsers has a 2000 character length limit. So theoretically I can only store 55 IDs in it.

How to increase the number of the IDs stored in browser uri?

It looks like an unsolvable problem, but perhaps there are workarounds to achieve the goal.

---

UPD
From the server side (relational database) it looks like this. There are two database tables with a one-to-many (or possibly many-to-many) relationship. And we need to filter the "primary table" by "foreign keys" (our IDs).

At the client side, we fetch the IDs from the "foreign table". Then the user selects some of them (we manage state of the selected IDs in the browser uri) and makes a request to get the filtered data from the "primary table".

Comment: Save the list in a database, along with a short string that's generated randomly. The URL can contain this short identifier, then your server looks up the list in the DB to expand it.

Comment: This is similar to the way link shortener services like tinyurl.com work.

Comment: But how can I decode the ids from the shortened url that way?

Comment: You look them up in the database.

Comment: I got it. So I need an extra service on the back end of the app to store those hashes along with ids

Comment: Yes. You're saving URLs that point to a server, so you can run the service there.

Comment: This is a big project and we have a backend team. I could ask to develop such a service. Thanks for the advice man!

Comment: It shouldn't be a complicated application.

Comment: But this required 2 sequential requests to the API. The first is to get a list of ids by hash, the second is to get a list of items by  list of ids

Comment: This would be done internally within the API, it doesn't require round-trips from the client.

Comment: Are the IDs in the multi-select immutable/persistent? If so, you can create a canonical order, then create a bitmask from their selection states and simply use that as the encoded state token in the URI, avoiding the need to store data for every "share". Decoding would work in reverse from the bitmask.

Comment: The IDs are not immutable. I have updated my question. Could you check?

Comment: @Edshav In that case, I’d go with [Barmar’s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72834979/how-to-store-large-list-of-ids-in-the-browser-uri#comment128647369_72834979). The “randomly generated short string” should have entropy greater than or equal to a [UUID v4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/randomUUID). ([`nanoid`](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) is comparable.)